# import/export according to environment variable

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, environment-variables, storybook

For a clientSide app I would like to select a specific import according to the environment variables that were setup in the package.json.

eg:`

```js
if (process.env.IS_DEV)
    import { store } from '../../../index.js
 else
    import { store } from './index.js';
```

`

Is there anyway to do this.
I currently receive the error -

> Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Comment: What about using `require` instead?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `import` can be only at top level.

If you are using some bundler such as `webpack` or `parcel`, you can use a `require` instead.

**Pay attention**: that both of the implementations will be inside the bundle, and only one of them will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web pack  dynamic import to enable this if you are using web pack 1

```
$ npm install babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack --save-dev
```

then in .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-webpack"]
}
```

https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack

in the newer versions of web pack, you can do this without Babel

https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import

the other solution which mentioned before is using require

but i think here you can do it in a different way to avoid having this files in the bundled result you can add build script to run before building the dist which replace this import inside the file completely before bundle it to frontend app

Comment: How would you do that (add build script to run before building the dist which replace this import)? I am using storybook to render a react component which uses store.getState()

Comment: As an example, you can have two files script.prod.js and script.js and in scripts section in package.json add script that executes the command `mov  script.prod.js script.js'  if the environment variable value is production

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is better to check `process.env.IS_DEV` inside the store file and export different values based on the current env